# Getting varstack pillar-data for different host

Tags: salt-stack

I'm using varstack (https://github.com/conversis/varstack) as an external pillar for Salt. The idea is much like Hiera to produce different pillar data for different hosts, and the setup works great for regular use.

Now I want to configure icinga2 to monitor all hosts present in salt, and pull their respective information from varstack/pillar to be able to use it in the configuration files for each host in icinga2. For now I've set up Salt Mine which enables me to add all the hosts to icinga2 atleast, but I still want some information from varstack for each host.

Does anyone have any idea how to do this?